# How do I save iwconfig interface mode to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to make a script that saves the Mode on the wireless interface to a Variable. In better words I want a variable called $mode that saves the Mode output of iwconfig. When iwconfig returns Mode as "Mode:Managed" it would assign "Managed" the variable $mode and when iwconfig returns "Mode:Monitor" it assigns "Monitor" to the variable $mode. End goal is to be able to do `echo $mode` and it would return "Monitor" or "Managed".

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `sed`:

```
mode=$(iwconfig | sed -n '/Mode:/s/.*Mode://; s/ .*//p')
```

This operates on a line containing *Mode:*, removing everything from the beginning of the line until and including *Mode:*, then removing everything from the first space to the end of the line.

The -n option suppresses printing the lines processed by `sed`. The `p` command outputs the line of interest.

The result of the command is then assigned to `mode`.

Definitely not the only possible method.

Note that this solution assumes a certain `iwconfig` output format, which may change without notice. I.e. it's risky.

Comment: This is almost perfect but this script now outputs "wlan0 Managed" or "wlan0 Monitor" is there any way to exclude "wlan0".

Comment: What is the output of `iwconfig`?